# XY Grid - SASS - columns margins / gutters

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6, gutter

I'm currently building a 4 blocks layout with Zurb Foundation 6.5.0 like this:

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
.blocks_4 {

    @include xy-grid;
    text-align: center;

    div {
        @include breakpoint(small) {
          @include xy-cell(12);
        }

        @include breakpoint(medium) {
          @include xy-cell(3);
          // @include xy-cell(3, $gutter-output: false);
        }

    }
}
```

I would like to remove the white gutters between the blocks (I drew the red arrows to point them out on my screenshot) so that they are sticking together and using the whole page width.

How can I achieve this with SASS? The SASS Foundation documentation is really lacking some examples... I tried using the `$gutter-output: false` but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me. The answer was simple:

```
@include xy-cell(3, $gutters:0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the gutter set on the parent (/container) instead of the children (/cells)?

I bet you can override the gutters by just setting the margins to 0, like so:

```
.blocks_4 {

    @include xy-grid;
    text-align: center;

    div {
        @include breakpoint(small) {
          @include xy-cell(12);
        }

        @include breakpoint(medium) {
          @include xy-cell(3);
          margin-left:0;
          margin-right:0;
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: I tried that, it does remove the margins but then it's not taking the full page width anymore: https://ibb.co/ifkOsf 
There should be a sass option for doing this. If you look at the documentation this is feasible using CSS classes (with or without gutters)

Comment: In fact this can be achieved with the mixin directly!

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve the same thing without having to add any additional SCSS (which will add weight to your app/site's compiled CSS file) and you would just use Foundation's XY grid with HTML:

```
<div class="grid-x text-center">
  <div class="cell medium-3">3 cells</div>
  <div class="cell medium-3">3 cells</div>
  <div class="cell medium-3">3 cells</div>
  <div class="cell medium-3">3 cells</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The idea of using the SASS version is to not use the CSS classes. CSS classes are a problem on big projects when you want to make global changes, where you would have to modify all your html templates. And it will not add much more CSS, the footprint is quite small actually